# Heroku Cedar Application With Multiple Web Facing Processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to configure a `Procfile` to support multiple web endpoints (either by port or subdomain)? Something like:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
admin: bundle exec unicorn -p $ALT_PORT -c ./config/admin/unicorn.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the `web` will get bound to a port, if you need multiple web endpoints you can either configure multiple dns entries to point at the same app, or you can deploy multiple seperate heroku apps. What do you hope to achieve by having two different process types with the same application code and we access?

### Update

I may have been wrong about the port only getting set for a web process.

You can run `$ heroku run bash` and then `$ echo $PORT` and it looks like one gets set. However I have no idea how requests get routed to those processes versus the web process.

Comment: I want to run the admin portion of an application on separate dynos from my application (for performance reasons) without having two apps.

Comment: You can also have the Procfile execute a bash script, and in the bash script pick based on an ENV variable which process to run. This will require separate heroku apps (each with that ENV variable set appropriately), but will allow to keep a single repo for your codebase and allows you to expose each process as a separate web endpoint.