# Best way to organise multiple endpoints within a single app

Tags: java, heroku

I am new to Heroku and I have a question on how to best organise my JAVA app to run on the platform.

The app I am developing will expose 3 REST endpoints. In order to properly scale the app I am thinking about running each endpoint on a dedicated dyno. The logic behind each endpoint isn't very complex and I am planning to keep it within the web dynos that run the endpoints.

At the moment I have a single app with all 3 endpoints running on the same web dyno. 
What's the best way to split my app so that I can have a process type per endpoint? 
Should I create 3 different apps (one per process type) or can I define multiple process types (JAVA commands?) within a single application? What would my procfile look like?

Comment: NOTE: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429687/heroku-cedar-application-with-multiple-web-facing-processes/12431992#12431992) which is somewhat related but does not really describe best practices on how to organise multiple endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most people would have a single application and scale dynos appropriately as the load increases. That is the benefit of Heroku, you just add more dynos in order to scale up if your app is designed correctly.

I don't think this is a Heroku question as such, but more a question of your application architecture, which is going to be hard to comment on without more information (and Java knowledge, which I don't have ;)

Comment: As you are suggesting, the application needs to be architected in a way that is compatible with how Heroku scales its resources (ie. dynos). Heroku says that each dyno will run a single "process type" and that it is [possible to define a single application that contains multiple processes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles). I guess my question now becomes more of a JAVA related question which is: How do I define multiple processes, commands or entry points within the same app so that they can individually be assigned to dedicated dynos?

Comment: Yes, you can have a single application which contains multiple processes, but usually these would serve different purposes. For example, you may have 3 dynos (or processes) that run the **website** parts of your application - which may contains 3 different endpoints -  and 1 dyno which runs a background proccess to send emails asynchronously.